# trouble with json_encode() when options are passed as a variable

Tags: php, json

This works:

```
$text = "hullo world";

$display = json_encode($text, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Returns:

`"hullo world"`

This does not work:

```
$text = "hullo world";
$options = "JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK";

$display = json_encode($text, $options);
```

Returns:

`Warning: json_encode() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in /pathtomyscript/myscript.php on line 11`

I am running PHP 5.3.3 which I understand does not support all the json_encode options that are supported in newer versions, but why is this one failing specifically when the option is passed as a variable?

Values for other options have similar results.

Comment: I guess you mixed up your examples, since the second one is right.

Comment: sorry, yes, will fix now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) is a [constant](http://www.php.net/constants), not a string.  It represents a number.

You want to do:

```
$options = JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK;
```